# Android- Can`t get ksoap2 to work with my nusoup webservice

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, nusoap

**Resolved**

i am trying to resolve this error but i really can`t figure it out, the reason my "transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);" always gives error. My web service is very simple and i tested it with SoupUI,i build it in php using nusoap. Hope someone can help.Thank you in advance.

Error Description:Open Declaration void org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(String soapAction, SoapEnvelope envelope) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException

> Resolution; In order to fix my "transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope)"
>   error, i had to do two things, 1º i used this line of code
>   System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");, because appears that
>   is a problem of ksoap2 for api < 9, and after that i just added the
>   permission on android manifest for internet and it worked.

This is my android code

```
//SOUP web service
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "urn:primeFactorization#doCalc";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "doCalc";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:primeFactorization";
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.33/androidWebService/calcNumber.php";
```

//Connects to webServer

```
public SoapObject getPrimeFactorization(String number) throws Exception{
    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");//--> This resolved my problem
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);


    request.addProperty("number",number);       
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    //envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try{
    transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //This is were i get the error:S<----
    Log.v("TEST","runs ok attributes "+envelope.getResponse().toString());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
}
```

//and my Web service WSDL

```
<definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:primeFactorization" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="urn:primeFactorization">
<types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:primeFactorization">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="doCalcRequest">
    <part name="number" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="doCalcResponse">
    <part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<portType name="primeFactorizationPortType">
    <operation name="doCalc">
        <documentation>Calculates the prime factorial of a given number</documentation>
        <input message="tns:doCalcRequest"/>
        <output message="tns:doCalcResponse"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="primeFactorizationBinding" type="tns:primeFactorizationPortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="doCalc">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:primeFactorization#doCalc" style="rpc"/>
        <input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:primeFactorization" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:primeFactorization" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="primeFactorization">
    <port name="primeFactorizationPort" binding="tns:primeFactorizationBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://192.168.1.33/androidWebService/calcNumber.php"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix my "transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope)" error, i had to do two things, 1º i used this line of code System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");, because appears that is a problem of ksoap2 for android api < 9, and after that i just added the permission on android manifest for internet and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

use this instead to get the result of your request:

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
Log.v("TEST","runs ok attributes "+result.getProperty(0).toString());
```

Comment: I tried, but it  didn`t worked for me, it triggers an exception "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: sorry I just saw that you have function that retrun value, you have to retrun result from your function and then to get the message use result.getProperty(0).toString()); or change the type of retruning in your function to string and then retrun result.getProperty(0).toString()); immeditally

Comment: yes you are right, i had another way for getting the result but yours is much simpler, thank you.